# Build failure for QtD on Linux Mint 16

Tags: linux, d

I'm trying to build QtD for my Linux Mint 16 machine according to the instructions [here](http://www.dsource.org/projects/qtd/wiki/BuildLinux). I get as far as `make`, which gives off a bunch of warnings from the generator (which the instructions tell me to ignore). I then try calling `sudo make install`, and instead get the following error:

```
make[4]: *** No rule to make target `install'.  Stop.
make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/install] Error 2
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/install.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/install.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [install] Error 2
```

I assume this means I failed, and I'm unsure what I did wrong.

Comment: report the problem to qtd. we can't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd heard that QtD was no longer maintained. Certainly, the last commit on dsource was 3 years ago: http://www.dsource.org/projects/qtd/browser

However, [the d wiki](http://wiki.dlang.org/GUI_Libraries) has a [link to bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/qtd/repo) where someone has a version of it which had a commit as recently as December. So, I guess that someone revived it and put it up on bitbucket.

However, regardless of whether the bitbucket repo is now indeed the "official" QtD repo, given that the last commit to the dsource repo was 3 years ago, the odds are very high that it no longer compiles, even if you use the correct build commands. So, I'd advise checking out the bitbucket repo and seeing if you can get that to work rather than trying to get the version on dsource to work. And even if you could get the dsource version to work, it's clearly unmaintained, so you're not going to want to use it long term, whereas the bitbucket version does appear to have had work done on it relatively recently.